# How to migrate an oracle database to sql server database

Tags: sql-server, oracle

What is the process for doing this ? I need to do this as my client does not want reporting off the live oracle database and want to put it on a sql server database as people there are familar with that database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to migrate completely then Microsoft have a Migration Assistant which is very good http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh302876(v=sql.105).aspx , alternatively if you are looking to import some of the data into SQL Server then a standard ETL package in SQL Server Integration Services should do what you need.